# geometry - how to construct the "net" of a two-frequency geodesic dome of radius x?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, solid-geometry

I'm new to this community. I am trying to construct a small (16 cm radius) geodesic dome with the northern celestial hemisphere inscribed on the exterior surface. I have a few questions, but I'll separate them into different topics.

My first and most basic question is because I am making this dome model without struts, and because I would like to easily disassemble and reassemble it, it would be helpful to know how to construct a net of the dome.

How do I construct the net of a two-frequency geodesic dome (based on an icosahedron) of radius *x*?

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e8/e7/14/e8e7141ece4cfee113aa56dc36ac65d5--greenhouse-film-backyard-aquaponics.jpg